How to Remove or Customize Connecting Lines Between Close Markers in React Native Map Clustering?
I'm currently using the "react-native-maps" library with the "react-native-map-clustering" for clustering markers on my map. I have a large dataset of markers, and the clustering works well. However, I've noticed that when markers are close to each other, they get connected with a red line, which I want to remove.

Here is the code:
<MapClustering
        ref={mapRef}
        rotateEnabled={false}
        paddingAdjustmentBehavior="never"
        animationEnabled={false}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        style={styles.map}
        customMapStyle={mapStyle.flat()}
        initialRegion={mapRegion}
        onRegionChangeComplete={handleRegionChangeComplete}
        showsUserLocation
        showsMyLocationButton={false}
        clusterColor="#fff"
        clusterTextColor="#000"
      >

